# Render view from application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have search form, and search is avaliable obviously from any page.
I thought that it makes sense, that such action from application controller is placed in layouts/views folder.
But I just don't get- Rails doesn't see it. So I can't do this? How then should I provide action, avaliable from any page?
Code:

```
def tests_search
  @tests=Test.test_search(params[:query])

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  end
  end
```

Route:

```
 search_tests GET    /search_tests(.:format)             application#tests_search
```

Form:

```
 <%= form_tag search_tests_path, {:id=>'test_search',:method => :get} do%>
```

Error:

```
  Unknown action

The action 'tests_search' could not be found for ApplicationControllerr
```

Comment: Try to restart your server maybe

Comment: applications_controller#tests_search => view should be placed in app/views/application/test_search.html.erb. or what exaclty is your question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new search controller. Use `rails g controller search index` which will create a search controller with a `index` action (you could also call the action something like `result`). Then add a `search/_form.html.erb` file in your search view folder, with the form:

```
 <%= form_tag search_path, {:id=>'test_search',:method => :get} do |f| %>
```

and render this in your `layout/application.html.erb` where you want it to be:

```
<%= render "search/form" %>
```

This way you have a search form on any pages, that uses the `SearchController` to handle the search requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using other controller to do this. It can be for example `SearchController` even if there will be only one method.

Notice that `ApplicationController` is controller that every other controller in application inherits from by default. So if it wouldn't be the case, it could make sense, but now every controller will inherit your `test_search` action, which is not desired.

If your search form will be a partial, then there is no difference whether this is in `ApplicationController` or in any other controller. You just have to point to right route.

Answer (score 1):

Initially you have to explain yourself the flow. What you need is some partial which is rendered on all pages, and if a user adds some input to it and submits, he gets some output. Right? Good. So you start by creating a new partial somewhere in

```
app/views/shared/_search.html.erb
```

Then, you create your route in routes.rb to point to a controller's action. You don't have to place this in application_controller. Instead, create your search_controller.rb and create some action which responds to the form submission there.

Whenever you want to render your search form on other pages, you simply call render partial ([more on that here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)) with something like

```
<%= render "shared/search" %>
```

This is good if you created the file above. Make sure your action exists and the name is correct, in your case it should be:

```
def test_search
...
end
```

Good luck.